# Convert char to pre-defined ascii value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a char '╞' with ASCII value (198). How I can manipulate this char such that the resulting char will be one of the following?

0 to 9 and A to F

Later on, I want to convert the resulting char back into the original char i.e. '╞'

Comment: `char c = '╞'; c = 'A'; c = '╞';` - You haven't made your problem very clear.

Comment: *Which* of the following?  Chosen randomly?  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: The application is storing data as hex chars i.e. ('0' to '9') --- ('A' to 'F'). I need to embed a boolean value into one of these chars. The char and bool are packed successfully but of course, the resulting char has ASCII value beyond that of hex digits. In this case, it is 198. I want some formula with which the resulting char would be within the range '0' to '9' or 'A' to 'F'.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is a question about decimal to hex conversion. I would do it like this

```
char dec = 198;
char hex[3];
sprintf(hex, "%02X", (unsigned char)dec);
```

To convert back it would be

```
int tmp;
sscanf(hex, "%X", &tmp);
dec = tmp;
```

There's other ways, using std::stringstream for instance, but the above is fine by me.